# Calcular cuantas horas y minutos han pasado desde una fecha en Java

Tags: java, date

Quiero guardar en una base de datos la fecha actual (día + hora + minutos) y luego recuperarla en Java y calcular la diferencia de horas respecto a la fecha actual.

No obstante, me gustaría que la hora no fuese obtenida a través del sistema, para evitar que el usuario pudiera modificar la hora del SO, puede tratarse de la hora GMT ya que el único fin de la función es calcular el tiempo transcurrido entre la hora guardada y la actual.

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Si el usuario puede acceder al sistema y cambiar la hora, también podrá acceder a la BD y modificar la hora allí. En todo caso, como no presentas código y está todo muy nebuloso (¿arquitectura?¿de dónde se tiene que sacar la hora si la del sistema no va bien?) voto para cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: no necesariamente, la bd puede estar en otro servidor, y la hora (GMT/UTC) la podés obtener de un servidor ntp ver https://stackoverflow.com/q/4442192/1423096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En su día hice una pequeña clase para poder sumar y restar fechas, tan solo tiene que obtener dicha fecha en milisegundos. Puedes usarla para obtener una fecha que des en el constructor para obtener los datos de esa fecha en formato String, o puedes instanciar la clase sin constructor y usar el método `operateCustomDate`, en el que operation puede ser 0(para sumar fechas) o 1(Restar fechas) a una `Date date` en la que se le añaden o restan(según la operacion que elijas) los milisegundos dados en el tercer parámetro: `milliseconds`. 
Espero que le sirva

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;


public class DateCalculator {

public Date Date;

public String Day;
public String Month;
public int MonthValue;
public String NumberDay;
public String Year;
public String TimeZone;

public String Seconds;
public String Minutes;
public String Hours;

public DateCalculator(Date date) {

    this.Date = date;

    String DateString = date.toString();

    //System.out.println(DateString);

    String[] DateSplitted = DateString.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < DateSplitted.length; i++) {
        //System.out.println(i + ". " +DateSplitted[i]);
        switch (i) {
            case 0: {
                this.Day = DateSplitted[0];
            }
            case 1: {
                this.Month = DateSplitted[1];

                LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
                this.MonthValue = localDate.getMonthValue();
            }
            case 2: {
                this.NumberDay = DateSplitted[2];
            }
            case 3: {
                String[] hour = DateSplitted[3].split(":");
                this.Hours = hour[0];
                this.Minutes = hour[1];
                this.Seconds = hour[2];
            }
            case 4: {
                this.TimeZone = DateSplitted[4];
            }
            case 5: {
                this.Year = DateSplitted[5];
            }
        }
    }
}

public DateCalculator() {
    /* EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR FOR USE THE CLASS WITH 
     CUSTOM VALUE CALCULATOR (operateCustomDate()) */
}

public String getDay() {
    return this.Day;
}

public String getMonth() {
    return this.Month;
}

public String getDayNumber() {
    return this.NumberDay;
}

public int getNumberMonth() {
    return this.MonthValue;
}

public String getCompleteHour() {
    String CompleteHour = this.Hours + ":" + this.Minutes + ":" + this.Seconds;

    return CompleteHour;
}

public String getCompleteDay() {
    String CompleteDay = this.Year + "-" + this.Month + "-" + this.NumberDay + " " + this.getCompleteHour();

    return CompleteDay;
}

public String getHour() {
    return this.Hours;
}

public String getMinute() {
    return this.Minutes;
}

public String getSeconds() {
    return this.Seconds;
}

public String getTimeZone() {
    return this.TimeZone;
}

public String getYear() {
    return this.Year;
}

/*

operation: 
        0: +
        1: -

Operate with the current Date

NOTE: FOR BIG LONG VALUES IN MILLISECONDS, USE 
long milliseconds = Long.parseLong(String number value);
 */

public Date operateCustomDate(int operation, Date date, long milliseconds) {
    long CurrentMs = date.getTime();

    long FinalDate;

    if (operation == 0) {
        FinalDate = CurrentMs + milliseconds;

        Date newDate = new Date(FinalDate);

        return newDate;
    } else if (operation == 1) {
        FinalDate = CurrentMs - milliseconds;

        Date newDate = new Date(FinalDate);

        return newDate;
    } 
    return null;
}
}
```

Para poder obtener los datos de la base de datos, al ser java yo usaría la librería jdbc, de la que dejo un tutorial por [aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-introduction.htm), una vez obtenida una String de la fecha, puedes usar la clase `SimpleDateFormat`, cuya documentación puedes encontrar [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Esta clase permite pasar la String a Date por lo que ya podría hacer las operaciones que necesite.

Comment: faltaría el detalle de obtener la fecha y hora desde un servidor externo

Comment: Cierto, ahora edito la respuesta @aloMalbarez