# ¿Cómo calcular la diferencia entre dos fechas?

Tags: java, date

A ver tengo una App que cada vez que inicia, se sincroniza con la BBDD, pero antes de sincronizar, recupero la fecha de la ultima sincronización de la base de datos. Por otro lado obtengo la fecha actual, como compruebo que ha pasado un día o mas antes de sincronizar?

Por cierto, todo esto en Java.

**Digamos que tengo:**

```
     Date fechaActual;
     Date fechaUltimaSincro;
```

como compruebo que fecha actual es 2 días mas tarde que fechaUltimaSincro por ejemplo?

Comment: Echa un vistazo [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173704/calcular-cuantas-horas-y-minutos-han-pasado-desde-una-fecha-en-java/173708#173708)

Answer (score 4):

**ya he encontrado solución**

```
    Date fechaUltimaSincro;
    Date fechaActual;

    int dias=(int) ((fechaActual.getTime()-fechaUltimaSincro.getTime())/86400000);

    System.out.println("Hay "+dias+" dias de diferencia");
```